# Facing error during OpenCV installation using Anaconda

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I am trying to install OpenCV package from Anaconda command prompt using `conda install cv2` but I keep getting the following error. I tried installing other packages but it gives the same error. Any feedback?

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3) C:\Users\user>conda install cv2
Fetching package metadata ...CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None for url https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win64/repodata.json.bz2 Elapsed: None n HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL. GTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

ConnectTimeout(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.continuum.io', port
=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/free/win-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConn
ction object at 0x0000001AB6BA5898>, 'Connection to repo.continuum.io timed out
(connect timeout=9.15)'))",),)

Answer (score 0):

Your command were wrong, it should be:

```sh
conda install opencv-python
```

Answer (score -1):

This was a firewall issue. Disabling the firewall resolved the issue and I was able to install opencv package.